# Elasticsearch field as searchable/not searchable

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a situation where I'd sometimes turn off whether a field is searchable or not, and for that I tried to use index when posting to mapping.

```
{
    "properties": {
        "test": {
            "type": "text",
            "index": false
        }
    }
}
```

I've found that it's not possible to switch index to true later once it's set to false. Same goes for store. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it's generally not possible to modify a mapping once it's been created. There are [just a few settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#change-existing-mapping-parms) that you can change but not the ones you mentioned.